# Keep track of each created template based singelton

Tags: c++, templates, generics, singleton

for my project I need to create singletons of a generic type. 
Those singletons manage the generic types in a *std::map* with ID to Object.
Here is my used code:

```
template <typename tComponent>
class InternalComponent {
public:
static InternalComponent& getInstance() {
    static InternalComponent s_result;
    return s_result;
}

void add(const tComponent& component, int id) {
    m_components[id] = component;
}

void remove(int id) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    auto it = m_components.find(id);
    if (it == m_components.end()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Component can't be found.");
    }

    m_components.erase(it, m_components.end());
}

void replace(const tComponent& component, int id) {
    auto it = m_components.find(id);
    if (it == m_components.end()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Component can't be found.");
    }

    m_components[id] = component;
}

tComponent* get(int id) {
    return &m_components[id];
}

private:
    InternalComponent() {};
    InternalComponent(const InternalComponent&);
    InternalComponent & operator = (const InternalComponent &);

    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::map<int, tComponent> m_components;
};
```

In order to delete all *Components* with a specific ID from each singleton, I have to keep track of each created instance of the singleton.
At this point I'm stuck.

The first problem is the generic type which can't be saved to a *vector*.
I would bypass this with an Baseclass and derive InternalComponent from it.

However I would still be unable to save the references to a vector.

Also I'm unsure how to check if the singleton is created for the first time, without using an if-statement in each getInstance call, to avoid duplicates entries in my list of created singletons.

My final question would be: How can I manage each created instance of an InternalComponent in a single list.

Comment: Isn't a singleton meant to provide exactly one object instance?

Comment: Well it still gives exactly one instance for each type.

Comment: Don't struggle with pointers, better use [Scott Meyers Singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289). If you want to count how many types were instantiated use a base class with a static counter variable.

Comment: Indeed, pointer, dynamic allocation and static data are easily becoming a mess.

Comment: To me this screams "reconsider design".

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I'm using the exact same pattern as you suggested. The pointers are use for the later saved objects. And I do not want to count them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how I can keep track of all my created template based singleton.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void delete(int id) = 0;
};

std::vector<Base*> test;

template<typename T>
class S : public Base
{
public:
    void delete(int id) override {
        //delete the component
    };

    static S& getInstance()
    {
        static S    instance;
        return instance;
    }

private:
    S() {
        test.push_back(this);
    }; 
public:
    S(S const&) = delete;
    void operator=(S const&) = delete;
};


int main()
{
    S<int>::getInstance();
    S<char>::getInstance();
    S<char>::getInstance();

    for (auto s : test) {
        s->delete(666);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

I use an abstract class to later store a template based class inside a vector. The class provides the functions which are later needed. The constructor only gets called once, which allows me to store the this pointer and avoiding uneeded checks.